# How to find out who added uncovered lines of code?

Tags: java, code-coverage, sonarqube

In Sonar unit test coverage reports, is there a way to figure out which developers have added uncovered lines of code in a given period (say, for example last 2 days)?

Does it require a sonar plugin to be written? Or is there something available already?

Comment: If you go to the lines, can't you find out from your SCM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently there's only one plugin that do what you want, a commercial one (Developers CockPit) : http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/developer-tools/developer-cockpit/

Comment: I guess this is exactly what I was looking for. Not sure if we will be able to use it though (due to the license cost). Thanks!